# Is there any way to remove the "Theorem" in theorem block titles?

Tags: beamer, theorems, naming

I'm writing a `beamer` presentation and using the `theorem` environment in the standard manner:

```
\begin{theorem}[Subject]
this is text
\end{theorem}
```

Which creates the textbox with the proper look but my problem is with the title, right now it is `Theorem (Subject)` while I would like it to be only `Subject`.

I'm thinking there should be a way to change the title while still using `theorem`.

Comment: And what about `block` environment in beamer? It would typeset what you want.

Comment: Honestly it's just that I've already written a lot of `theorem` in the slides and I don't have any experience with `block`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can achieve that with `amsthm`, cf. the following minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\newcommand\mybeamerthm[2]{%
  \newtheorem*{#1}{#2}%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{#1}{%
     \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=yellow,bg=blue!40}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}

\mybeamerthm{subj}{Subject}
\begin{subj}
  theorem on subject
\end{subj}

\mybeamerthm{foo}{bar}
\begin{foo}
  theorem on bar
\end{foo}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) preloads [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm), so there should be no reason to load it explicitly.

Comment: Depends on whether or not you set the noamsthm option to the documentclass, but since i didn't set it you are of course right. I changed the answer

Comment: I would also be tempted to define `subj` in the document preamble, rather than in the frame. It's just good practice to separate content from structure. Add in the reference to `beamer` loading `amsthm`, and I'll delete my comments.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for but I forgot to add in the theorem block I switched some colors like the answer in this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87216/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-text-in-a-theorem-in-beamer . Which environment would I need to replace theorem with in this case?

Comment: Ok this is getting tricky on the moral side :). Werner generally i'd agree, the problem is each and every one of these theorems will be a one shot solution (unless you hack around it with a macro or two), that's why i did put them close to the only point they'd be used. 
Given that the \AtBeginEnvironment command expects the environment to be defined already this needs to come after the definition, so I guess my objection is becoming moot.

Comment: With the updated solution you could even create a command/environment that takes the name of the theorem and creates the correct environment on the fly and squeezes the content in between. If you like it nasty you could even redefine theorem to that so you don't have to edit your document. That would be rather on the dark side though and i strongly advise against it.