# Beamer - numerating theorems and color of block

Tags: beamer, numbering, color

Why won't it numerate my newly defined theorem block. And can i change the color of the block?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newtheorem{teorem}{Teorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definicija}{Definicija}[section]
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}[section]
\newtheorem{primjer}{Primjer}[section]
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Konjektura}[section]
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color,tabularx,pstricks,pst-plot,amsfonts,amsmath,tensor,amssymb,graphicx,graphics}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{default}
\title{Fibonaccijevi brojevi i zlatni rez. Rekurzije. Fraktali}
\author{Amar Bapić, Merjem Vikalo, Irma Zenunović}
\date{}
\institute{Univerzitet u Tuzli\\Prirodno - matematički fakultet\\ Odsjek Matematika}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{Fraktali}
\begin{frame}{Fraktali}
\begin{teorem}
\end{teorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beamer has a build-in option to number theorems, you can activate it with `\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]`

The question how to colour it, has already an answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87219/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtheorem{teorem}{Teorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definicija}{Definicija}[section]
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}[section]
\newtheorem{primjer}{Primjer}[section]
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Konjektura}[section]
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tabularx,pstricks,pst-plot,amsfonts,amsmath,tensor,amssymb}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{default}
\title{Fibonaccijevi brojevi i zlatni rez. Rekurzije. Fraktali}
\author{Amar Bapić, Merjem Vikalo, Irma Zenunović}
\date{}
\institute{Univerzitet u Tuzli\\Prirodno - matematički fakultet\\ Odsjek Matematika}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\AtBeginEnvironment{teorem}{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=red!40}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \section{Fraktali}
    \begin{frame}{Fraktali}
        \begin{teorem}
            test
        \end{teorem}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Comments**

- Please do not load packages two times, e.g. `\usepackage{amsfonts}, \usepackage{amssymb}`
- as beamer itself already provides these functionalities, there is no need to load `hyperref, color, graphicx, graphics`

---

**EDIT**

To show the section number in the title, try

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle{\insertframetitle}{\thesection.~\insertframetitle}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. Also, how do I show the section number?

Comment: @zermelovac The first number should be the section number

Comment: I mean in the title "Fraktali". I want there to be "1. Fraktali"

Comment: @zermelovac Ah, now I understand. I will see what I can do

Comment: @zermelovac see the edit

Comment: Can I use a similar method to add the number in the header where the title is?

Comment: @zermelovac The navigation entries are tricky, maybe ask a new question about them.